# Visual Studio 2008 & Perforce. Where is my .vspscc files?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, perforce

I use Visual Studio 2008 and Perforce.
When I bind my project to perforce(File -> Source Control -> Change Source Control -> Bind),
Visual Studio complain like "~.vspscc File is not under source control".
Should I create that file for myself, or is that file created by Visual Studio?
If it is created by Visual Studio, why does it complain about it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding a project to source control you should right click over the solution name in the Solution Explorer and select "Add Solution to Source Control..."

This will add all the files to Perforce (or what ever source control system you are using) and create the necessary support files and put them under source control as well.

The Change Source Control option is only used when you are changing which source control system you are using. For example if you have one project in Perforce and another in Subversion.

Comment: Thanks. But, my situation is a little bit complicated. I will ask about that again. :)